# Google Cloud Kuberneties: Finding the external IP address for pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster to GCP. For this cluster, I added some deployments. Those deployments are using external resources that protected with security policy to reject connection from unallow IP address.

So, in order to pod to connect the external resource, I need manually allow the node (who hosting the pod) IP address.

It's also possible to me to allow range of IP address, where one of my nodes are expected to be running.

Untill now, I just find their internal IP addresses range. It looks like this:

```
Pod address range 10.16.0.0/14
```

The question is how to find the **range of external** IP addresses for my nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin with the IPs that are assigned to Nodes:

- When we create a Kubernetes cluster, GCP in the backend creates compute engines machines with a specific internal and external IP address.
- In your case, just go to the compute engine section of the Google Cloud Console and capture all the external IPs of the VM whose initials starts with gke-(*) and whitelist it.
- Talking about the range, as such in GCP only the internal IP ranges are known and external IP address are randomly assigned from a pool of IPs hence you need to whitelist it one at a time.

To get the pod description and IPs run `kubectl describe pods`.

Comment: Thanks for response. Doing it to specific node - I'm understand. Doing it on auto-scaled cluster, not.  You wrote: "GCP only the internal IP ranges are known and external IP address are randomly assigned from a pool". A specific region have a range of IPs or it's just random?

Comment: It is not random, but google said they will move the ranges if needed. You can check the [Alias IP Ranges Overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip) docs. Also there is the script to find all gcp compute ranges written by Anthony Elizondo on his [github](https://gist.github.com/complexsplit/0a099c37df8ca6c7c855cc7bcdf127b7)

Comment: There's an official list of GCE IP ranges: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range

Or the JSON data file itself: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json

Putting entire GCP regions into an allow list would obviously mean anyone running anything in that region will be able to access your service, but I guess it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the compute engine instance page it shows the instances which make the cluster.  it shows the external ips on the right side.    For the the ip of the actual pods use the Kubectl command.